# Верикальный TextView в заголовке таблицы

Tags: java, android, textview, table

В таблице может быть разное количество столбцов (3 - 12). Заголовок формируется путем добавления необходимого количества вертикально ориентированных однострочных TextView в TableRow.

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView TextView  " />
</TableRow>
```

Проблема в том, что чем больше элементов добавляется, тем меньше становится ширина каждого. И даже вертикально расположенный текст, обрезается. Пробовал задействовать всякие параметры, но так ничего и не получилось. На скринах приведена та же ситуация при статическом моделировании.

[image: текст вмещается]

[image: а здесь текст обрезается]

Посоветуйте, уважаемые, как добиться того, чтобы текст не обрезался ?

Comment: Если сделать комбинацию из `
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="none"`,то текст не будет резаться так сильно()

Answer (score 1):

Решение вскоре нашлось, в виде класса VerticalTextView.
После поиска и тестов многих подобных аналогов, был найден рабочий VerticalTextView.java:

```
package app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;

public class VerticalTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    final boolean topDown;

    public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    final int gravity = getGravity();
    if (Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
        setGravity((gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
        topDown = false;
    } else
        topDown = true;
}

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();
        canvas.save();
        if (topDown) {
            canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
            canvas.rotate(90);
        } else {
            canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
            canvas.rotate(-90);
        }
        canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());
        getLayout().draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

И пример использования :

```
        if (bPortretOrientation) {
            VerticalTextView cell = new VerticalTextView(ctx, null);
            cell.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            cell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.stat_table_header));
            cell.setTextSize(14);
            cell.setText(pName);
            cell.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            cell.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            cell.setRotation(180);
            TableRow.LayoutParams newLparam = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 240, 1f);
            newLparam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            cell.setLayoutParams(newLparam);
            return cell;
        } else {
```

Возможно, это поможет какому-нибудь новичку.